# Wordpress fast-cgi-bin 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, cgi-bin

I had a wordpress blog on a free host. It went through a maintenance days ago. 
Now I am not able to log into the dashboard.

I noticed in the wordpress webroot, there is a new `.fast-cgi-bin` directory.

When I try to login to `myexampleblog.com/wp-admin/`, it shows

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /.fast-cgi-bin/php53.cgi/wp-admin/index.php on this server.
```

I searched and tried to add Options `+ExecCGI` into a `.htaccess` file.

But it seems not working. Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is me guessing:

The hosting company updated the way the applications are served through their webservers (either added fastcgi support or reconfigured it) and somehow they borked the configuration.

Write an email to them with a full error description / message and ask them to look up the directory or php permissions, or what ever they guess what caused the error. (Since problems started with their update.)

If you did the update yourself, and the hosting is coming without any support, you should have ssh access to the server. In that case ask someone you know with proper sysadmin skills to fix it, should not be a big deal.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. The hosting company does not provide ssh access nor do I have too much knowledge about that. I got a system mail that they are going to end their service starting in July.. So it won't bother anymore.